# give more importance to smaller value in Numpy weightage average

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to weight average the output of different regression models. I have mean absolute error of each model. While averaging i want to give more weight to lower mae model.
The following code give more importance to higher mae value.

```
weights_mae=[1.640,1.675,1.514,1.563,1.667]
mean=np.average(val_list,axis=0, weights=weights_mae)
```

How can i give more importance to lower mae value.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest idea - make inverse of mae weights, small weights will become large and vice versa.

```
weights_mae=[1.640,1.675,1.514,1.563,1.667]
mean=np.average(val_list,axis=0, weights= 1 / weights_mae)
```